# Entity Framework: Linq to Json - retrieve collections of collections

Tags: json, linq, entity-framework-4

I have 3 entities:
1. A database
2. Table which database has a collection  of
3. Column which tables have a collection of

While lazy loading enabled = false

How do I return a json string containing each database, with an array of respective tables, each table with an array of respective columns?

**UPDATE:**

I have have been able to return the following Json script, at the cost of disabling instances on certain classes:

[image]

This is the return I am looking for. However, I had to line-out column's relationship to table, and table's to database in respective classes and I did not want to do that.

**I did first try the [ScriptIgnore] annotation over the foreign classes but that did not work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With clarification that these are custom-created objects, I believe you are looking to use reflection.  Specifically the [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) class which is returned from calling Object.GetType() will give you what you want.  If you have an object graph of database objects with table child objects and column grandchild objects, you should iterate through the graph, calling GetType() on each to acquire information about the names and types if needed.

Reflection is not fast and performant, but it should get what you need.

If the objects you are referencing are from a database technology:

Look at [Context.MetaDataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.metadataworkspace.aspx).  Specifically look at .GetItems().  [Here](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET24) is a good example/demo showing you how to do it.  Look at the 'EntityTypes' and 'EntityTypes and Properties' sections.

Excerpted code:

```
var query = from meta in context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
        where meta.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType
        select (meta as EntityType).Name;
```

This will get you the list of tables and columns.  You will not be able to get the list of databases on a given SQL server from an Entity context that is aware of only the items added to it and you do not add databases to a context.

I also just noticed you requested that you be able to return it in JSON; with the result set above, you should be able to loop through and either build the JSON by hand or construct an object that is serializable as JSON.

Comment: I think I may not have explained this well to you. These are not database structures in something like sql where sysobjects kicks in, these are entity classes I created.

Comment: Then the answer is perhaps simpler, if I understand you now.  Use reflection to acquire a propertyInfo class... I'll add link and information to my answer.

Comment: I should have asked earlier.  Can you please give me something to go on?  Can you show me the code you have for creating or querying (however you're acquiring) this list of Database/Table/Columns?  Further you are not querying from a database, so what is your understanding of how disabling LazyLoading will impact the solution?